# Injective Integral Operator on $L^2[0,1]$ or $C[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, integral-transforms

Consider an arbitrary $f \in L^2 [0,1]^+ $

where $L^2[0,1]^+$ is the function space of square integrable non negative functions.

We say $T$ is an Integral Operator if $T$ is of the form , $$ T(f) = \int_{[0,1]} f(x) K(x,y) dx  $$

It's well known that the Fourier Transform constitutes a bijective isometry integral transform between $L^2[\mathbb{R}]$ and $L^2[\mathbb{R}]$

Is there something similiar for compact intervals like $[0,1]$ ? Specifically I am wondering if there is an injective transform with a continuous inverse.

If it makes things easier is there such a transform for $C[0,1]^+$ ?

Note , I use the $+$ primarily since it might be easier to find an operator for non negative functions.

Comment: you mean $K$ is a function ? (i.e. $K(x,y) = \delta_y(x)$ such that $T = Id$ is not allowed). Then they are many conditions on $K$ that make $T$ compact, so that $T^{-1}$ cannot be bounded (continuous), but I would be unable to state the most general coniditions on $K$ letting us know $T$ is compact. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercer%27s_theorem

Comment: Yes K(x,y) is a function . For the Laplace Transform on $\mathbb{R}^+$ for example we would have $K(x,y) = e^{-xy} $

Comment: so you know Mercer's theorem ? then considering $T^*T $ you should get that if $K$ is regular enough, $T^*T $ is compact, so that $T^{-1}$ cannot be continuous

Comment: @reuns, so what if one considers $T$ is not compact? Are there some conditions such that $T$ has a bounded inverse?